# Is there any way to make the following code more efficient?

Tags: c

Hey, I just began programming, I was wondering if anyone could give insight or tips on how to organize code better or make something more efficient in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{

     /* Variable Definitions */

   int altitude, speed;
   float angle, combo, earthRadius, gravityAcceleration, horizontalDistance, pi, radians, time, verticalDistance;

   pi = 3.141592653589793238;

      /* User Input */

   printf("Let's play golf!\n\n");
   printf("Enter altitude [m]   : ");
      scanf("%d", &altitude);
   printf("Enter speed [m/s]    : ");
      scanf("%d", &speed);
   printf("Enter angle [degrees]: ");
      scanf("%f", &angle);
   printf("Enter time [s]       : ");
      scanf("%f", &time);
   printf("\n");

      /* Calculations */

   radians             = angle * (pi / 180);
   earthRadius         = 6.371E6;
   gravityAcceleration = 9.8 * pow((earthRadius / (earthRadius + altitude)), 2);

      /* Formula Definitions */

   horizontalDistance  = speed * (cos(radians)) * time;
   verticalDistance    = (speed * (sin(radians)) * time) - (0.5 * gravityAcceleration * (pow(time, 2)));

      /* Output Statements */

   printf("Horizontal distance  = %.1lf m\n", horizontalDistance);
   printf("Vertical distance    = %.1lf m\n", verticalDistance);

}
```

Comment: More efficient in what sense?  The program is very simple, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: If you remove all the calls to `scanf` and don't wait for user input, it will run much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

1. The correct definition of main would be `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. Or perhaps the shorter `int main()`. You should also `return 0` at the end of this function.
2. Since `pi` never changes a better definition would be `const double pi = 3.141592653589793238;` Or `#define PI 3.141592653589793238`.
3. Since you have used the `lf` modifier in your printf arguments you probably want to replace `float` with `double` for extra precision in all you variables. You probably want to replace `float` with `double` anyway for the reasons R points out in the comments.
4. If you want arbitrary precision floating point, you need to use a library for that, like [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/).

This won't speed up your code. They're just points for neatness.

Comment: `const float` is bad advice. Use `#define`. And don't use floats, use doubles. floats have very bad precision and no advantages except size, which only matters if you have thousands or millions of them.

Comment: Have replaced with `const double` and included an `or define` option. Does #define vs const have any noticable difference for accuracy?

Comment: in a real nitpick, it is usually prettier to `return EXIT_SUCCESS` from `stdlib.h` if memory serves. My C is rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is way too simple to optimize, maybe in the past on much weaker hardware it would have been relevant, however not on anything in use today.

However if you would like general pointers on optimization, then do a bit of reading on Algorithms and Data Structures, and have a look at the book "Code Complete" Second Edition. It has a section dedicated to optimization.